# class is not shown in elements inspector in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

as shown in the image and in the circled parts, i created a class called `clsTest`. in this class i would like to change the
position and some propertities of the circled element in red as shown in the image. the circled elements in red are composed of
input field and icon of the calendar.
when i activate the elements inspector in chrome, the class `clsTest` is never present or listed among other classes. in other words
,as shown in the image, the class `.clr-control-container` is shown but the class `clsTest`is not!!

please let me know how to correctly assign a class and be able to modify its attributes to change the position and properties of
the circled element in red.

**html**:

```
<clr-date-container class="clsDateContainer">
            <label id="idDateOfSprayLabel">
                <p>Date:</p>
            </label>
            <input id="idDateOfSprayValue" class="clsTest clr-control-container" clrDate type="date" placeholder="Specify date of spray" [(ngModel)]="iDatePasser.dateOfSpray" (ngModelChange)="onDateOfSpraySet($event)" name="dateOfSpray"
                value="2021-07-21" min="2021-01-01" max="2090-12-31" />
        </clr-date-container>
```

**css**:

```
.clsTest{
bottom: 10;
right: 0px;
left: 430px;
top: 174px;
width: auto;
```

}

**image**:

[image]

Comment: Where have you defined the styles of the class `clr-control-container` and where have you defined `clsTest` in contrast?

Comment: @gru both are in the css file

Comment: have you restarted your app since you added the styles?

Comment: @gru yes!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the default [Angular style encapsulation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) is causing this behavior here.

Try adding the pseudo class `:host` to your css like this:

```css
:host .clsTest{
  bottom: 10;
  right: 0px;
  left: 430px;
  top: 174px;
  width: auto;
}
```

The `:host` tells Angular to apply the styles directly on DOM elements (not based on components/templates). Optionally, you could also add `::ng-deep` to apply styles to all children of the selected element as well (where the CSS selector matches as well).

Answer (score 0):

The input has the class at the moment

To see the classes of the input element just click on it(in the Element section of chrome developer tools), I specify it on the image.

Keep in mind the sequence of the classes you give to an element is important. The second class will override the first one.

[image: Image was updated]